# MysqlDump does not work in space seperated path

Tags: java, mysql

mysqldump cannot create sql file if there is an space in path provided like

```
K:/My Folder/backup.sql
```

while if i create in any folder where there is no space, it easily creates it like

```
K:/MyFolder/HisFolder/HerFolder/backup.sql
```

I tried to find an answer but all in vein. I tried to replace spaces with %20 but not worked. I am using MysqlDump with Java to create backup. Both Java and Command Prompt replies same as

```
Got Error 1049: Unknown Database 'Folder/backup.sql' when selecting the database.
```

I also tried to put path in inverted commas etc but no use. My command is

```
C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --add-drop-database -u root -pabc --routines --database db_abc -r K:/my folder/backup.sql
```

Comment: Did you try using the MS-DOS version of the folder name?

Comment: i am using mysqldump with java to create backup. Java and Command Prompt both replies same

Comment: What I mean is, if "My Folder" already exists, does mysqldump work if you specify the folder as "MYFOLD~1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your path.  `"K:/My Folder/backup.sql"`

Comment: this is exactly the same answer as mine.

Answer (score 2):

Just add " around them

```
"K:/My Folder/backup.sql"
```